# When Combining a bubble sort with a selection sort why won't my program sort?

Tags: c++, sorting, bubble-sort, selection-sort

I am taking an intro C++ course and am having a bit of trouble understanding what is wrong with my sort.
First I know my formatting is not the best,sorry. I am learning and trying to improve it.
For a bit of context, I have written this same program for a previous assignment and for the most part it worked well. The difference is I used a simple bubble sort in the previous assignment that looked like this:

```
for(int i = 1;i <totalEmployeeCount; i++)
{
    for( j = 0; j < totalEmployeeCount - i;j++)
    {
        if(employee[j]->netPay > employee[j+1]->netPay)
        {
        payroll * temp;
        temp = employee[j];
        employee[j] = employee[j+1];
        employee[j+1] = temp;
```

But then I was tasked with combining my bubble sort with a selection sort. So I first wrote a simple sort in those parameters -

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int swap (int[],int,int);
int main()
{
int slot[10] = {8,3,1,5,7,10,4,9,6,2};
int n = 10,i;
int lower,upper,sml,sortflag,scan;
lower = 0;
upper = n - 1;
sortflag = 1;

while((lower<upper)&&(sortflag==1))
{
    sml = lower;
    sortflag = 0;
    scan = lower+1;

    while (scan<=upper-lower)
    {

        if (slot[scan]>slot[scan+1])
        {
            swap(slot,scan,scan+1);
            sortflag=1;
            if(slot[scan]<slot[sml])
                sml = scan;     
        }
        scan++; 
    }
    swap(slot,lower,sml);
    upper = upper - 1;
    lower = lower + 1;
}
cout<<"after while sort: "<<endl;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    cout << slot[i] << "  " << endl;
}
}

swap(int slot[],int i, int j){
int temp;
temp = slot[i];
slot[i] = slot[j];
slot[j] = temp;
}
```

And that worked fine. However when I attempted to implement my combined sort (an exsel sort as my teacher calls it) It no longer sorts. I get no error message, nor any warning (Using Dev C++) and the rest of the program operates as expected. The best I can figure is I am not passing parameters to the swap function correctly, however I am truly a novice and am not entirely sure I know what that means even as I type it. If anyone would be willing to help me understand my folly fully that would be awesome.  Thank you!

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
int hrs;

class payroll{
public:
    int employeeID, payStat;
    string firstName, lastName;
    double salary,hourlyRate, hours, otHours, regPay, otPay, grossPay, 
    taxRate, taxAmount, netPay;

public: void setVariables(int empID,string fName,string lName, int stat, 
double rate, double hrs)

{
    employeeID = empID;
     firstName = fName;
     lastName = lName;
    payStat = stat;
    if(payStat == 1){hourlyRate = rate;}
    else{salary = rate;}
    hours = hrs;
}

public: virtual double calculateGrossPay()=0;

double calculateTaxAmount()

{
    taxRate = .30; 
    taxAmount = grossPay*taxRate; 
    return taxAmount;
}   

double calculateNetPay()

{
    netPay = grossPay - taxAmount;
    return netPay;
}       // END CALCULATENETPAY() FUNCTION.

void printHeadings()

{
cout<<setw(45)<<"--PAY ROLL REPORT--"<<endl;
cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
cout<<"       NAME     ID   HW     OT  GROSS-PAY  NET-PAY   OT-PAY"<< endl;
cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
}   // end headings

void printData()

{
    cout<<setprecision(2)<<setiosflags(ios::fixed | ios::showpoint);
    cout<<setw(6)<<firstName<<setw(8)<<lastName<<setw(8)<<employeeID<<setw(6)<<hours<<setw(6)
    <<otHours<<setw(8)<<grossPay<<setw(10)<<netPay<<setw(10)<<otPay<<endl;
} 
};

class employeeSalary : public payroll
{
double calculateGrossPay() 
{ 
  double hourlyRate = (salary/2080);
  double regPay = (40*hourlyRate);
    if (hours > 40)
        {
            otHours = (hours - 40); //calculate OT hours
            otPay = (otHours * hourlyRate); //calculate OT pay
            grossPay = regPay;
        }
    else if (hours <= 40) 
        {
      otHours = 0; otPay = 0; grossPay = regPay;
        }
return grossPay;    
} 
}; 

class employeeHourly : public payroll
{
public:
    double calculateGrossPay()
   {
        double regPay = (hrs * hourlyRate); //calculate regular hours
            if (hours > 40)
            {   
                otHours = (hours - 40); //calculate OT hours
                otPay = (otHours * hourlyRate * 1.5); //calculate OT pay
                int reg = hours - otHours;
                regPay = reg*hourlyRate;
                grossPay = (regPay + otPay); //calculate gross pay
            } //end if clause for gross pay with overtime
            else 
            {
                otHours = 0;   otPay = 0; grossPay = regPay;
            } //end else clause for four hours
return grossPay; 
    } //end calculateGrossPay() function
}; //end EmployeeHourly class

 swap (payroll*employee[],int i, int j)
{
payroll*temp;
temp = employee[j];
employee[j] = employee[i];
employee[i] = temp;

}

int main()
{
int employeeCounter = 0;
int totalEmployeeCount,empID,stat,m;

int lower,upper,sml,sortflag,scan;
sml = 0;
scan = 0;
upper = totalEmployeeCount - 1;
lower = 0;
sortflag = 1;

double min,max,rate;
string fName;
string lName;
min = 2000.00;
max = 0;
cout<< "enter # of employees you want to process:  ";
cin>>totalEmployeeCount;
payroll* employee[100];
while(employeeCounter < totalEmployeeCount)
{
    cout<<"Is employee "<<employeeCounter+1<< " hourly or salary? (enter 1 for hourly / 2 for salary):";
    cin>>stat;
    cout<<endl;
    if (stat == 1)
    {
        cout<< "Instantiating a HOURLY employee object inherited from base class employee"
        <<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter employee's ID: ";
        cin>>empID;
        cout<<"Enter employee's first name: "; 
        cin>>fName;
        cout<<"Enter employee's last name: ";
        cin>>lName;
        cout<<"Enter employee's hourly wage: "; 
        cin>>rate;
        cout<<"Enter employee's hours for this week: "; 
        cin>>hrs;
        employee[employeeCounter] = new employeeHourly();         
        employee[employeeCounter]->setVariables(empID, fName, lName, stat, rate, hrs);
        employee[employeeCounter]->calculateGrossPay(); 
        employee[employeeCounter]->calculateTaxAmount(); 
        employee[employeeCounter]->calculateNetPay();
        cout<<endl<<endl;
            employeeCounter++; 
    } //end if

    else
    {
        cout<<endl<<"instantialting a SALARY employee object inherited from base class employee" <<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter employee's ID: ";
        cin>>empID;
        cout<<"Enter employee's first name: ";
        cin>>fName;
        cout<<"Enter employee's last name: ";
        cin>>lName;
        cout<<"Enter employee's Salary: "; 
        cin>>rate;
        cout<<"Enter employee's hours for this week: ";
        cin>>hrs;
        employee[employeeCounter] = new employeeSalary();         
        employee[employeeCounter]->setVariables(empID, fName, lName, stat, rate, hrs);
        employee[employeeCounter]->calculateGrossPay(); 
        employee[employeeCounter]->calculateTaxAmount(); 
        employee[employeeCounter]->calculateNetPay();
        cout<<endl<<endl;
        employeeCounter++;
    }
}
employee[0]->printHeadings();

while((lower<upper)&&(sortflag==1))
{
    sml = lower;
    sortflag = 0;
    scan = lower+1;

    while (scan <= upper-lower)
    {

        if (employee[scan]->netPay> employee[scan+1]->netPay)
        {
            swap(employee,scan,scan+1);
            sortflag=1;
            if(employee[scan]->netPay < employee[sml]->netPay)  
                sml = scan; 

        }
        scan++; 
    }
    swap(employee,lower,sml);
    upper = upper - 1;
    lower = lower + 1;
}
cout<<"after sort: "<<endl;

for (m=0; m < totalEmployeeCount; m++)
    {

        if (employee[m]->netPay > max);
        max = employee[m]->netPay;
        m++;
    }

for(int i = 0; i < employeeCounter; i++)
{
    employee[i]->printData();
}

return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Reduce this code to a [mcve].

Comment: Nobody will debug your code for you. Write a small example on paper, sort it by hand using the algorithm, and follow your code to see where it does something differently from your paper example.

Comment: @noSenseEtAl thank you! I understand that no one will debug my code for me. The issue on my part I think is a lack of full comprehension. In my basic sorting program I use no pointers, i just sort an array of integers. with my payroll program I am using a pointer ( I think this is correct?) in payroll*employee. I think the values are not being returned FROM swap into the main. is my understanding at least correct, or am I misunderstanding my own code?   Thank you.